# Can we make hypothesis test for a few variables while controling some other variables in a regression model?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, inference

My colleagues want to test some predictors in a regression model with the response of disease onset.

Let us say we want to know whether pre-diagnosis, bmi, and hormone level have significant associations with the diesease onset. Meanwhile, we have a lot of other variables which we are not interested in making a hypothesis testing but want to control for. Let us say age, education and income.

My first questions: is this a legit way to fit a regression model with all 6 predictor variables, among which we mean to control for 3 and make hypothesis testing for the other 3?

If this is legit, my second question is: We know we want to make Bonferroni correction for multple testing to control for family-wise error rate. But we are not sure whether we only need to correct for the three variables we are interested in making claim from (bmi, pre-diagnosis, and hormone), so the p-value threshold is 0.05/3? Or we want to use 0.05/6 ?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you cannot do an F test on the variables of interest? You are not forced to put all variables into such an F test. You can test the null that a group of variables are all zero, or you could construct more intricate test statistics that tell you if the sum of those variables equals some value or not.

Comment: @user7019377 Because we are interested in knowing the individual inference for a given predictor. We do not want to know, as a whole, whether the three predictor have significant association with the outcome. We want to know: whether prognosis has significant association? whether age has significant association? etc. Thanks.